# Trouble training model using scikit-learn, shell restarts

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a project involving heavy text mining (based on the steps outlined in the DataCamp course "Machine Learning with the Experts").

I have a 'vectorizer' step in my Pipeline to perform tokenization.

```
('vectorizer', HashingVectorizer(token_pattern=TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC,
                                 non_negative=True, 
                                 norm=None, 
                                 binary=False,
                                 ngram_range=(1, 2),
                                 n_features = 2 ** 18
                                )
)
```

Although it takes a while, the above step works fine when 1-grams and 2-grams are considered. I had to reduce n-features from the default value of 2 ** 20 to make it work.

As a next step I want to consider feature interactions so I added this step to the pipeline.

```
('int', SparseInteractions(degree=2))
```

The code for SparseInteractions can be found here
https://github.com/drivendataorg/box-plots-sklearn/blob/master/src/features/SparseInteractions.py

The problem is that after a while the shell restarts without any kind of indication of what went wrong. Seems like adding interactions is too much for my laptop to handle. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve/get around this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of laptop and OS do you have? This feels less like a Python problem and more like a machine problem. I know my laptop has identical symptoms any time I run out of RAM in a Python shell.

Comment: Hi Hans,
Thanks for helping.
I have a Lenovo ideapad with 8 GB ram. 
Could you please share how you dealt with this issue?

Comment: In my case, I did the job in batches, writing intermediate results to the disk so I didn't use up all the RAM. That might not even be your issue though; any hardware/software bug can cause the same effect. I would start by running the process with some sort of resource monitor up to check see if RAM is even the problem.

Comment: It does seem like a RAM issue. I simply used Task Manager to monitor the usage. 
Could you please elaborate on the batching approach you used?

Comment: The batching approach I used isn't likely to apply here since it solves a different problem. If your problem doesn't have extremely high sparsity, you might be looking at terrabytes -- more than can even fit on the disk. If you did want to try that approach, you would need to find out what is being stored in RAM and use something like [numpy.savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) to break the matrices involved into blocks and store each in a different file. Using the blocks depends on the desired purpose.

Comment: Even if each feature only takes 1 byte when your data is fairly sparse, the fact that `SparseInteractions` is looking at pairwise interactions on `2**18` data points indicates an approximate minimum size of the data structure of around 32 gigabytes.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments and feedback Hans. I will see how to go about it. I think I will have to reduce the number of features.